# I want to know if this sentence is correct

Tags: word-choice, phrases

> Jake decided to learn as many different artists, styles and works as often as possible.

I think the first 'as' is not needed. OR
'and' is needed between 'works' and 'as'.

Let me know if the sentence itself is right or my thought is right.

Answer (score 3):

Is it wrong?  That depends on which grammar books you read.  But it's certainly a very bad sentence.

People read long sentences by breaking them into small pieces, and reading them a small piece at a time.  So if you have a sentence with a structure like this:

> a b.

and you have another sentence with a structure like this:

> c b.

then, when you combine them, like this:

> a c b.

you are giving the reader a problem, because when the reader sees *a c* they are confused.  It is often much better to just to repeat the *b*, like this:

> a b, c b.

And your sentence is, indeed, much easier to read like this:

> Jake decided to learn as many different artists, styles and works **as possible**, as often as possible.

I'm pretty sure that:

> ... as *X* as possible, as *Y* as possible.

is commonly used, and nobody has a problem with it.